# Java - Interface - How do I assign a specific interface in multiple activities all together

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

I have a `service` which has an `interface`, I'm `implementing` the `interface callback` in multiple `activities`, but because of I'm calling the app `instance` on every `activity's` `onCreate`, the `interfaces` are responding on the current `activity` only. How do I make sure they work all together in every `activity`.

`MyApp.java`

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static MyApp myApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myApp = new MyApp();
    }

    @Contract(pure = true)
    public static synchronized MyApp getInstance() {
        MyApp myApp;
        synchronized (MyApp.class) {
            myApp = MyApp.myApp;
        }
        return myApp;
    }

    public void setCallBackListener(MyService.ReceiversCallbacks receiversCallbacks) {
        MyService.receiversCallbacks = receiversCallbacks;
    }
}
```

`MyService.java`

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public static MyService.ReceiversCallbacks receiversCallbacks;

    public MyService() {
        super();
    }

    public interface ReceiversCallbacks {
        void onReceiveCallbacks(String data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Background service")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (MY_LOGIC) receiversCallbacks.onReceiveCallbacks("DATA_FROM_MY_LOGIC");

        //stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`ActivityA.java`

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity implements MyService.ReceiversCallbacks {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         MyApp.getInstance().setCallBackListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveCallbacks(String data) {
           // calling important functions
    }
}
```

`ActivityB.java`

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity implements MyService.ReceiversCallbacks {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         MyApp.getInstance().setCallBackListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveCallbacks(String data) {
           // calling important functions
    }
}
```

Each activity's `onCreate` when I do this `MyApp.getInstance().setCallBackListener(this);` The focus of the call back shifts to the new activity. But I want the focus in both or more activities at the same time, how do I do that? Is there any better way for the solution I want?

**Please note these:**

- I don't want to call those functions `onResume`
- I don't want to use `Broadcasts`

Comment: You are modifying same static `receiversCallbacks` again and again this is why only latest one will get update.. Also this is not a not a good practice it will crash outside of Activity's lifecycle ..  An idiomatic Way to do that is to Use [`Bound Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) or you can use a `Broadcast`/EventBus to provide callback to all Activities..

Comment: I don't want to use `Broadcast`, Can you provide me code for `EventBus`

Comment: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @ADM I tried Event bus but that wasn't working with multiple events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created different interfaces for each activity and registered them to their corresponding activity, and they worked!

`MyApp.getInstance().setCallBackListener(this);`