# Event Bus - Create Multiple Events

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

How can I create multiple events using an event bus?

So in this example, I'm trying to receive multiple events. But when `addEvent3WhenLogicOccers()` is called values of `addEvent1WhenLogicOccers()` are gone because of `new EventBusEvents()` in the event bus post. I want to receive both `EVENT_1` and `EVENT_3` with their data which is `my_event_child_1` and `my_event_child_3`. How can I do it?

```
String EVENT_1 = "my_event_child_1";
String EVENT_2 = "my_event_child_2";
String EVENT_3 = "my_event_child_3";

addEvent1WhenLogicOccers() {
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new EventBusEvents(EVENT_1));
}

addEvent3WhenLogicOccers() {
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new EventBusEvents(EVENT_3));
}

@Subscribe(sticky = true)
    public void onEvent(EventBusEvents eventBusEvents) {
        switch(eventBusEvents.eventChilds) {
               case EVENT_1:
                   // on event 1 code
                   break;
               case EVENT_2:
                   // on event 2 code
                   break;
               case EVENT_3:
                   // on event 3 code
                   break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out `EventBus` wasn't the best solution for me. I used interfaces instead [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467272/11969024)